# Can someone explain to me why this series diverges?

Tags: convergence-divergence

I have this series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{3+\cos k}}$$

I understand that if the exponent is fixed (not a function) and greater than 1 the series converges (p-series) but I can see in wolfram that this series diverges clearly (wolfram says that the comparison test shows that the series diverges... but I dont know what series is using on the comparison).

Comment: Just to be clear, did you mean for the summand to be $\dfrac{1}{a^{3+\cos k}}$ instead of $\dfrac{1}{a(3+\cos k)}$?

Comment: The first. Sry, I did some mistakes. I put _a_ but I was talking about harmonic-type series and not geonetric-type derivations.

Comment: Now, you don't have the variable $a$ anywhere in the summation.

Comment: @JimmyK4542, yes, sorry for the first mistakes... No _a_, just a derivation of Riemann series with function on exponent. Sry first mistakes. If I put _a_ it isnt what I was trying to compare.

Comment: Is $n$ a constant?  Or did you mean $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^{3+\cos(k)}}$$

Comment: $$\frac{1}{k^{3+\cos k}}\leq\frac{1}{k^2}$$ so convergent, no?

Comment: @RobertIsrael,@Jp McCarthy GOD, sry guys. Yes, is _k_, I fixed it. Sry. Now is the correct version what Im trying to know. Sry.

Comment: Then the comparison $$\frac{1}{k^{3+\cos k}}\leqslant\frac1{k^2}$$ shows that the series converges, not that it diverges.

Comment: Well if we have finally got to $\sum\frac{1}{k^{3+\cos k}}$, that obviously converges.

Comment: Please do not delete the considerations related to the Wolfram program.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys. I get a bit confused trying to understand [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918931/does-the-following-series-converge).

Comment: @Did I deleted because I get confused with a different function. I was seeing various sum on wolfram. The consideration that I deleted was about a different sum not the sum on the question. Sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $3 + \cos(k) \ge 2$ for all $k$, $\dfrac{1}{k^{3+\cos(k)}} \le \dfrac{1}{k^2}$, so this series converges by the comparison test. You might have confused Wolfram by using $n$ instead of $k$: if $n$ is a constant the series 
$\sum_k \dfrac{1}{n^{3+\cos(k)}}$ diverges because the terms are bounded below.

Comment: Yes, surely it was some confuse thing that I did. I was seeing various sums on wolfram and I surely "mixed" things of differents ones. Sry.

Answer (score 2):

This series is **convergent**. Since $\cos k\ge -1$,
$$\frac{1}{k^{3+\cos k}}\le \frac {1}{k^2}.$$
It would be more interesting if it were $\frac{1}{k^{2+\cos k}}$.

Comment: Can you extend on the example with 2 instead of 3? Please? I will appreciate.

Comment: Masacroso: You should be aware now that the series of general term $1/k^{2+\cos k}$ is an entirely different story... hence asking about it on the present page is inappropriate.