# convergence of a series, exponent involving $\cos k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

In an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919018) the problem was raised of the convergence or divergence of
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2+\cos k}}\ .$$
The problem was (quite properly) dismissed as being significantly different from the original question.  But I would like to know the answer, so here it is as a separate question.

Clearly the difficulty is that while $2+\cos k$ is always greater than $1$, there is no $\varepsilon>0$ such that $2+\cos k$ is always greater than $1+\varepsilon$.

Any ideas?

Comment: [This](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=239929) and [this](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=69242) are related.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/testing-the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1nk-cosn

Comment: Thanks for the references guys, will follow them up.